# Transactions in SQL Server stored procedures when invoked via Linq2SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, linq-to-sql, transactions

If we invoke a SQL Server stored procedure from a C# application through Linq to SQL data context like this:

```
this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()))...
```

would the framework not wrap it automatically in a transaction scope?

The stored procedure in question may have multiple Update/Select statements with LOCK hints, and no explicit transaction defined in its DDL.

Edit: a general question about SQL Server stored procedures: in case we use a transaction from C# to invoke it, would all the statements inside it be part of that single outer transaction, or would individual statements be wrapped in their own implicit transactions?

Comment: Is it really Linq To Sql? That's a very old technology now..

Comment: It is Linq 2 SQL.

Comment: And by "transaction scope" do you mean [this C# class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netcore-3.1) and its related namespace? Have you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/transaction-support) ? Do you have an active C# side transaction at the time you call the stored procedure?

Comment: There is no explicit Transaction Scope created for stored procedure call, Also I noticed that Linq 2 SQL would wrap the method call in an implicit transaction if we call `SubmitChanges()`. I noticed that in our implementation we are not using `SubmitChanges()`, nor `TransactionScope`

Comment: Regarding your last question, the explict transaction started by the application will control the transaction. All the statements in the proc will be executed in that outer transaction and committed/rolled back as dictated by the app code. Without the outer transaction, each statement is executed in autocommit mode (committed if no errors or rolled back if errors occur).